# Start individual instances during cloud foundry push synchronously

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

Not entirely sure if this is possible but is there a way to start the specified cloud foundry instances in sequence rather than having them start concurrently?

Right now using the default cf push command with build-pack, 2 instances to be spun up. Would like to do this on the push if possible.

Any ideas if this is possible?

thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to run a poller, one instance of my app only - turns out I could do this by using the [`CF_INSTANCE_INDEX`](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#CF-INSTANCE-INDEX) environment variable and ensure that it only ran on one instance.

This negated the need for a hackier solution of a sequenced start of the instances and a lock file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `cf push --help`, that doesn't seem to be possible...

However, if your goal is to start instances in sequence, maybe the [`cf scale` command](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-scale.html) is an option for you:

```
$ cf push myapp -i 1
$ cf scale myapp -i 2
```

You could wrap these commands plus some logic into a script that would start N instances sequentially.

Comment: Yeah this is a useful command to know also - I had a poller running and don't have a database up and running so I could not use Quartz, I was able to query the instance to ensure my spring poller only start / runs on instance zero - which negated the need to start them in sequence, handy command to know going forward though.